# Android Java Retrofit - Filtrar listas en spinners(AutoCompleteTextView) para que el siguiente muestre la lista correcta

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-spinner

Tengo un app que debe filtrar una lista de PROVINCIAS,DISTRITOS, CORREGIMIENTOS,LUGAR POBLADO.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos datos los obtengo mediante retrofit

```
 //Obtener provincias
public static ProvinciasService getProvinces(){
    ProvinciasService provinciasService = getRetrofitClient().create(ProvinciasService.class);
    return provinciasService;
}
//Obtenemos distritos
public static DistrictService getDistrict(){
    DistrictService districService = getRetrofitClient().create(DistrictService.class);
    return districService;
}

//Obtenemos corregimientos
public static CorregimientoService getCorregimientos(){
    CorregimientoService corregimientoService = getRetrofitClient().create(CorregimientoService.class);
    return corregimientoService;
}

//Lugar Poblado
public static LugarPobladoService getLugarPoblado(){
    LugarPobladoService lugarPobladoService = getRetrofitClient().create(LugarPobladoService.class);
    return lugarPobladoService;
}
```

La listas para cada endpoint se muestran correctamente pero necesito que al hacer click en una Provincia en especifico el siguiente spinner cargue solo los distritos de esa provincia y asi sucesivamente para corregimientos y lugar poblado.

Estructura de los modelos:

Provincia:

```
private String ID;
private String Nombre;
```

Distrito:

```
 private String ID;
private String Nombre;
private String ID_Provincia;
```

Corregimiento:

```
private String ID;
private String Nombre;
private String ID_Distrito;
```

Lugar Poblado:

```
private String ID;
private String Nombre;
private String ID_Corregimiento;
```

En mi actividad Formulario obtengo las provincias de esta forma:

```
private void getAllProvinces() {
    List<Province> provinces = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<Province> adapterProv = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, provinces);
    Call<List<Province>> callProvincesList = RetrofitClient.getProvinces().getProvinces();
    callProvincesList.enqueue(new Callback<List<Province>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Province>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Province>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                for (Province province : response.body()){
                    String nombreProv = province.getNombre();
                    String idProv = province.getID();

                    Province province1 = new Province(idProv, nombreProv);
                    provinces.add(province1);

                    adapterProv.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                    dpProvincia.setAdapter(adapterProv);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Province>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Al final para cada spinner tengo algo igual al hacer click

```
dpProvincia.setOnItemClickListener(dpProvinciaListener);

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener dpDistritosListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            District district = (District) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            String idProvByDistric = district.getID_Provincia();
            Toast.makeText(FormActivity.this, "ID Distrito segun provincia "+ idProvByDistric, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

Si ven obtengo el ID de Provincia pero no tengo claro como pasar esto al siguiente para obtener los datos especificos.